# How to upload csv with FastAPI and process it in memory with Pandas?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to upload a csv file with FastAPI and then load it into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import io, base64

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/uploadfile/')
async def create_data_file(
        experiment: str = Form(...),
        file_type: str = Form(...),
        file_id: str = Form(...),
        data_file: UploadFile = File(...),
        ):
    
    #decoded = base64.b64decode(data_file.file)
    #decoded = io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8'))
    
    print(pd.read_csv(data_file.file, sep='\t'))

    return {'filename': data_file.filename, 
            'experiment':experiment, 
            'file_type': file_type, 
            'file_id': file_id}
```

I tried using the `file.file` content directly or converting it with `base64` or `StringIO`. I also tried `codec`. The error I get with the example code is

> ```
> AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'readable'
> ```

Comment: You do not want to save the file?

Comment: Not as csv. I want to convert it to parquet.

Comment: I would be curious to see an example of the file that failed. The method above works for me. (only difference is my test files are not tab-separated)

Answer (score 7):

Changing the encoding to what suits you best, I found this workaround:

```
from io import StringIO
 
pd.read_csv(StringIO(str(data_file.file.read(), 'utf-16')), encoding='utf-16')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround using libraries `csv` and `codecs` to create the records which then can be turned into a pandas dataframe:

```
def to_df(file):
    data = file.file
    data = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(data,'utf-8'), delimiter='\t')
    header = data.__next__()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
    return df
```

Comment: This works great on my side but I need to use the second row of my csv as my Dataframe header. How can I choose which row will be the header?
If I do `header = data.__next__()` it will by default take the first row of my csv as header